# Nuxt watch route only for specific path

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am showing some images in my app. let's say images are showing on *domain.com/wallpaper* route.
I am showing with fetch() method and watch for query and params with this code.

```js
watch: {
  "$route.query": "$fetch"
},
async fetch() {
  console.log("fetched");
  //My Code
},
```

It works fine on the same route. But when I go to the homepage or any other page, this fetch() also gets called one time.
How can I stop calling this method on change to another route?

Comment: So you want to trigger `fetch` only on a specific route if the query params change, but not when the route changes? In which file did you put the code?

Comment: @tho-masn in wallpaper page

Comment: Btw, the last `watch` is run because it's value is changed. My answer (below) is mainly this: checking what is the next path and not running any code if it's something else than `wallpaper`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of code should do the job.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="$router.push({ name: 'wallpaper', query: { search: 'mountains' } })">
      look for mountains
    </button>
    <button @click="$router.push({ name: 'wallpaper', query: { search: 'nuxt' } })">
      look for nuxt
    </button>
    <button @click="$router.push({ name: 'index' })">
      Go back to the homepage
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  watch: {
    async $route(to, from) {
      if (to.name !== 'wallpaper') return // if you're going to somewhere else than `wallpaper`
      // the `return` will end the execution and not go further

      console.log('fetch logic here in case you stay on the wallpaper route name')
      await this.fetch()
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

You could maybe also call the `fetch()` method again when you do change your query.

Comment: this.$fetch(); will work. BTW I'm adding this code in OnPageChange method from pagination.

Comment: @mukeshsoni not sure what is `OnPageChange`. But glad it works fine!

Comment: In pagination component when clicked on any page number, OnPageChange is called.

Answer (score 0):

For Nuxt2, you can use `watchQuery` to only watch query updates.

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-watchquery

**Example:** Fetch will get executed as soon as any query param changes, but not on route change:

```js
export default {
  watchQuery: ['any-query-param'],

  async fetch() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Even if this one is kinda related to the issue, doesn't it get triggered when you leave the `wallpaper` path too?

Comment: Just did a quick test, where `fetch` didn't get triggered after a route change. Not sure though if the setup was equal to the one from the question. But even if it would get triggered, it is possible to filter out these cases, if `watchQuery` is used as function (like mentioned in the docs).