# How force nuxt-link to re render the same page

Tags: vue.js, routes, nuxt.js

When nuxt-link path and route path are equal & User clicks to the link nothing happens

But I need the page gets re-rendered (I don't want full refresh like using an "a" tag)

I'd like only the content of the specific page get's updated

and I want this happen for all of my links so I am looking for an easy way to do it

I searched but I didn't found anything useful enough to solve this

I used :key for nuxt-link and it doesn't work I don't know why buy I am using i-18n module for translations and it has a method localePath, it's related to it ?

anyways my code is like this

```html
<nuxt-link :to="localePath({path:'/trade?market=BTC_USDT'})">BTC</nuxt-link>
```

Comment: Can you please share your code? Also, what needs to be re-rendered? Some async data or the Vue instance itself? `$forceUpdate` is pretty heavy and not a good practice since it's a nuke but you may try this: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-forceUpdate Why don't you let your app being reactive by triggering some watched state?

Comment: Btw, what is your path supposed to do? Do you have a specific action tied to it? Because, if you're not supposed to move to another page but simply filter, a `button` may be more adequate here. And you could set a watcher for your route as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69085375/8816585) to then trigger a specific action.

Comment: I want Vue Instance gets re rendered not only some async data, cause for  example in trade page I have charts that even if data get re fetched it doesn't get updated till it get re rendered & I in some pages I may not have any data request but still i want this behavior of loading same page....

Comment: Then, if some new data is fetched properly, the issue here is more about why your charts are not updated. Don't bypass the issue by nuking Vue's reactivity, try to find out why this is not reacting to your updated values. You're maybe in this case: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays Lastly, why do you want to "load the same page". If you don't need to "move", don't force it. Rather find the reactivity issue.